# POST de arquivos com AJAX retornando nulo

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, post

Tenho seguinte HTML:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

---

```
<form action="{{route('clinic.picture.add.ajax')}}" method="post" 
               enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pic-form">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="files" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="add-file">
</form>
```

Quando seleciono o arquivo de imagem executo o seguinte script

```
$('#add-file').change(function(){
    let form = $('#pic-form')[0];
    let data = new FormData(form);
   // pic.append('file', $('#add-file'))
    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "{{asset('clinica/addPicture')}}",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Rota do Laravel

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
  Route::prefix('clinica')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/addPicture', 'Clinic\Dashboard\ClinicController@clinicAddPictureAjax')
             ->name('clinic.picture.add.ajax');
 });
});
```

Metodo na controladora

```
    public function clinicAddPictureAjax(Request $request)
    {
        \Log::alert($request);
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $data = ClinicPictureRepository::createClinicPictures($request,
                                   Auth::user()->id);
            DB::commit();
            return response()->json($data, 200);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollBack();
            \Log::alert($e->getMessage());
            return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 500);
        }
    }
```

Porem quando executo a requisição para o servidor me é apontado que nada esta sendo enviado, este é o log mostrado no laravel.

```php
[2019-10-29 12:51:57] local.ALERT: array (
)
```

Alguém saberia dizer o que esta errado na requsição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure:

dessa forma no seu [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

sendo que essa configuração fica global na sua applicação e não tendo mais necessidade de utilizar isso em todos os códigos, faça essa rotina em um lugar que será visto pelos os seus outros códigos [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). <sup>***Referencia:*** [Laravel csrf token mismatch for ajax POST Request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867849/6797930)</sup>

A outra parte do problema pode ser resolvido assim seguindo aquele `<form/>`:

```
$('#pic-form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('clinic.picture.add.ajax') }}",
   method:"POST",
   data:new FormData(this),
   dataType:'JSON',
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    console.log(data);
   }
  })
});
```

<sup>Referencia: [Upload Image in Laravel using Ajax](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/upload-image-in-laravel-using-ajax.html)</sup>

Dessa forma você vai resolver os problemas, no seu código original, tem configurações erradas e desnecessárias, que no final das contas causam problemas no envio dos dados.

Comment: Infelizmente desse modo a requisição para o servidor nem chegou a ocorrer...

Comment: Qual é o erro do debug da janela do navegador apertando F12 guia console? @BetiniO.Heleno

Comment: No PHP do laravel
```php
array (
  '_token' => '7shXUmsknBVwilpavXqmJe1gyBjlS2hnKhINHtpZ',
  'files' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'download.jpg',
     'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

Comment: No js retorna um ``` { } ```  apenas....Parece que nao esta enviando nos modo 'multipart/form-data',

Comment: O senhor estava certo...Aconteceu que no HTML eu esqueci de colocar o 
```name="files[]" ``` de modo a entender que era um array, uma vez que meu metodo no repository para salvar é foreach encima de várias imanges..Obrigado, estava completamente correto sua resposta